# Desktop file for my Python script

Tags: linux, python

I would like to make a `.desktop` file for my Python script, but so far the only thing i have is a clickable icon on my desktop! It does nothing when I click it, so im guessing there is something wrong with the execution :)

The desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Python
Exec=/home/user/MyDocs/Python/EasySteer/Main.py
Name=EasySteer
Icon=steering_wheel
X-Icon-Path=/usr/share/icons
```

and I also tried:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/xterm "python /home/user/MyDocs/Python/EasySteer/Main.py"
Name=EasySteer
Icon=steering_wheel
X-Icon-Path=/usr/share/icons
```

But nothing works :D if it matters this is for my Nokia N900 mobile phone that runs Maemo linux, but I think the basics are the same.

Comment: Make sure your script is executable (`chmod u+x`) and that the first line of the script is a "shebang line" like `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=EasySteer
Icon=steering_wheel
Type=Application
Exec=/home/user/MyDocs/Python/EasySteer/Main.py
Terminal=true
```

Adding `Terminal=true` should cause the default terminal emulator to be opened.